# Получить доступ к сайту, использующий сертификат безопасности

Tags: python, ssl

С недавних пор сайт https://roskazna.gov.ru/
требует наличие корневого сертификата Минцифры для доступа к информации

Я установила этот сертификат себе на комп (Mac OS) и на самом сайте отображается, что соединение защищено.

Ранее был написан парсер, который в свободном доступе собирал доступную информацию, но сейчас обычный get-запрос недоступен

```
import requests

url = 'https://roskazna.gov.ru/'
r = requests.get(url, verify='rootca_ssl_rsa2022.cer')
r.status_code
```

Ошибка:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='roskazna.gov.ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

P.S. использую jupyter notebook для написания кода

Answer (score 1):

Не хватает промежуточного сертификата.

Некоторые Вэб сервера отправляют промежуточный сертификат вместе с сертификатом сайта, но этот настроен не так. Промежуточный сертификат нужно также обозначить доверенным.

Перейди на сайт https://www.gosuslugi.ru/crt. В разделе для линукс скачай оба сертификата. Открой их в блокноте и соедини текст в одном файле chain.pem:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Получишь ответ с блокировкой от роботов, но без ошибок ssl

```
>>> r = requests.get(url, verify='chain.pem')
>>> r.status_code
403
```